# Huffman Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, information-theory

We use Huffman’s algorithm to obtain an encoding of alphabet ${a,b,c,d}$ with frequencies $f_{a}, f_{b}, f_{c}, f_{d}.$ In each of the following cases, either give an example of frequencies $(fa, fb, fc, fd)$ that would yield the specified code, or explain why the code cannot possibly be obtained (no matter what the frequencies are).

(a) Code: ${0,10,110,111}$

(b) Code: ${1,00,01,110} $

(c) Code: ${00,01,10,11}$

I mostly solved part $b$, but could not be able to solve $a$ and $c$. Would be welcomed to know your solutions on this!

Comment: It's been a few years since I studied Huffman but in my opinion $(b)$ is not possible since there should be at-least two alphabets with maximum code length of $3$. For $(a)$, $f_a=0.39,f_b=0.31,f_c=f_d=0.15$ seems to work. For $(c),f_a=f_b=f_c=f_d=0.25$ seems to work.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Thanks initially for your comment. Coming to part (b), could you please elaborate on what you mean by "there should be at least 2 alphabets"? Moreover, should not we provide trees as examples for part (a) and (c)? Or what are these values that you have mentioned? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, if we have the longest code $110$, we must also have the code $111$ since we form pairs of alphabets with lowest frequency.

Comment: The question asks to give the frequencies (or more conveniently probabilities), not the tree. The tree can be built from the frequencies, right?

Comment: Actually it did not ask about probabilities, therefore I was confused on part a and c. Could you please provide more details on what you mean, for example, probability of 39 for $f_{a}$?

Comment: Moreover, how would it be possible to construct a tree using your example probabilities? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ShubhamJohri By trees, I mean as in the following tree example with 3 frequencies:
https://www.slader.com/textbook/9780073523408-algorithms-1st-edition/163/exercises/15/

Comment: Yes, I am aware. I am writing an answer.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Huffman coding, we build the tree bottom-up by considering pairs of alphabets with the least frequency/probability. So the two least frequent alphabets get assigned the longest code length. In part $(b)$, $d$ has the longest code $110$ so some other alphabet must also have the code $111$ which is not the case.

In part $(a),c,d$ have the largest code length so they have the two least probabilities, say $p_c\le p_d$. We start building the tree by forming a dummy vertex labelled $v_1$ with left child $c$, right child $d$ and $p_1=p_c+p_d$. Then $v_1$ has the code $11$. Now $b$ has the code $10$, i.e. $b$ is the left child and $v_1$ is the right child of a dummy vertex $v_2$. So $p_2=p_b+p_1$ and $p_b\le p_1$. Since out of $\{a,b,v_1\},b,v_1$ have the longest codes, we also have $p_b,p_1\le p_a$.

Now $v_2$ has the code $1$. $a$ has the code $0$, i.e. $a$ is the left child and $v_2$ is the right child of the root vertex $R$. So $p_a\le p_2.$ So the constraints we have are$$\begin{align*}&p_c\le p_d\le p_b\le p_a\\&p_b\le p_c+p_d\le p_a\\&p_a\le p_b+p_c+p_d\\&p_a+p_b+p_c+p_d=1\end{align*}$$

You can check that $p_a=0.41,p_b=0.29,p_c=0.15,p_d=0.15$ is a solution and it generates the tree in the picture:

[image: Graph]

For part $(c)$, all alphabets have the same code length so one solution is when they are all equiprobable, i.e. $p_a=p_b=p_c=p_d=0.25$. Can you check if you get the correct tree and codes?

---

**Edit:** Your tree should look like this:

[image: Tree]

Note that instead of $a,b,c,d$ we could have $b,a,c,d$ or any other order of the four alphabets in the bottom four vertices since they have the same probability, but we have to make the tree according to the codes given. The below tree also corresponds to the given probabilities but the code for $b$ is $00$, which is not desired.

[image: Tree]

Comment: Note that we can talk of probabilities in place of frequencies. If $f_i$ is the frequency of alphabet $i$, then we assign it the probability $f_i/\sum f_i$. The probabilities so assigned preserve the relative order among the alphabets based on their frequencies.

Comment: Initially, I want to thank you for such a detailed explanation, appreciate it very much. For part c), I think I found the required tree, but would be eager to know yours since there may be some minor mistakes as well

Comment: If you could provide similar tree as in part a), I would definitely understand whether my tree is correct or not. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AnarRzayev Check the edit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your such detailed explanation!